# What is the original occurrence of this specific memory-loss / amnesia plot?

Tags: first-appearance

I am not searching for a specific movie I have seen, hence the question may be vague or a little off-topic (hopefully not too far). I am searching for the original movie (or source, maybe even in literature) that the following plot line originated from:

> Person A and Person B had a romantic relationship (boyfriend/girlfriend, married, or any form of love interest). Person B has an accident which results in memory loss / amnesia and does not remember anything specific about the relationship, hence starts a new life or relationship with person C. Person B is considered missing and searched for by person A, or person B stumbles upon person A. Person A discovers what has happened, however leaves it that way (possibly to personal grief) since person B is happy (or happier) this way.

Person B is likely to be female, person A is likely to be male. Person C does not have to exist, and if he does, person A may or may not confront him. Person A may find out about the accident from person B or person C. Person B may or may not be faking amnesia, and if not, the memories may or may not return. Also, person A may or may not decide to confront person B, in case he/she does, he may or may not tell person B about his/her past.

I know the current description allows for plenty of variation, but I think this kind of plot pattern is very recognizable and memorable. Innale, a Malayalam film from 1990, uses this plot line, though I doubt it originated from there. I have also seen it used elsewhere, but so far the aforementioned movie is the oldest source I know of.

Any ideas for the original source?

Comment: @coleopterist Are you going to retag all the `first-appearance` questions with `trope`? And what actually *is* a *"trope"* anyway?

Comment: @coleopterist True, yet most of the first appearances would be what you define as a trope, but nevermind.

Comment: @ChristianRau - a "trope" is a recurring literary theme. This is a modern usage of the term, sometime in the last 40-50 years.

Comment: There is some info. here at TV Tropes regarding the 'Amnesiac Lover' - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmnesiacLover

Comment: Moondram Pirai has a similar plot.

Comment: Certainly not the first occurrence, but The Red Squirrel (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106305/) had a (weird) variation of amnesiac love interest. I think the theme of memory loss (in the way you described or similar) was present in literature and possibly mythology way before movies. In Norse mythology there was one story in which a man was made to forget about the Valkyrie he fell in love with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brynhildr

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's truly the first appearance, but the 1915 movie [Garden of Lies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0005374/plotsummary), which is based on a 1902 novel of the same name, has this structure:

- A man and woman get married.
- There's a car accident, and the woman gets amnesia.
- The man has to go away on a long trip to Europe.
- She hires a man to pretend to be her husband to "jar her memory."
- Do I really need to tell you what happens next?